# Check values of all fields of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, how do I check the values of all option tags inside of a certain div.class to make sure they are set?

Comment: When is an option "set"?

Comment: No, on form submit -- just wan't to make sure the user selects something other than the default placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allSet = true;

$(".myClass select").each(function(i, el){
    if($(":selected", el).length == 0){
        allSet = false;
        return false;
    }
});

if(allSet == false){
    alert("All selects are not set. :(");
} else {
    alert("All selects are set. :)");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the value attributes are set to something:

```
        <div class="myClass">
            <select>
                <option value="">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

$("div.myClass option[value='']").length === 0;
// => false
```

And if they're not:

```
        <div class="myClass">
            <select>
                <option>One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

$("div.myClass option[value]").length === 0;
// => false
```

Of course, those two checks can be combined like so:

```
0 === $("div.myClass option[value='']").length + 
      $("div.myClass option[value]").length;
```